# Excel VBA Plotting

Tags: excel, plot, linegraph, vba

I need to plot a line graph of a set of data using VBA on button click.

It Plots the data correctly but there are additional items which appear in the legends of the graph.

Here is a snapshot of the data and the graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9cAs.png)

Attached below is the code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Range("A2:D12").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$2:$D$12")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
     Dim ChrtSrs1 As Series, ChrtSrs2 As Series
    Set ChrtSrs1 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With ChrtSrs1
        .Name = "='Sheet2'!$B$2"
        .Values = "='Sheet2'!$B$3:$B$12"
        .XValues = "='Sheet2'!$A$3:$A$12"
    End With
    Set ChrtSrs2 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With ChrtSrs2
        .Name = "='Sheet2'!$C$2"
        .Values = "='Sheet2'!$C$3:$C$12"
        .XValues = "='Sheet2'!$A$3:$A$12"
    End With
End Sub
```

How do you remove the extra fields from the legends in the graph ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the table, saving, closing the workbook, re-opening, then running the code?  I have seen relics of older Series when re-creating charts in the same session of a workbook.

Comment: If this still happens after the above suggestion, do some tests to see what series numbers are being utilized (series1, series2, etc.), and you can manually delete the series number (go in reverse from say series5 to series 4) from the list.

Comment: You're both setting the `Source` property *and* adding new series.  Here's how I'd typically do it:  1) Add a chart  2) Remove any data series from that chart (depending on what's selected when you add the chart it may pick that up when you create it) 3) Add the data you want